# Is there a continuous version of $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ for the entire unit circle?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, circles

The fact that $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ only "works" for the upper-right quadrant makes some calculations (for a physics simulator) impossible. I of course use $atan2(y,x)$ in the code, that's not what I'm asking.

What I am asking is this: does there exist a single function $f(y:\mathbb{R}, x:\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \theta:\mathbb{R}$ that returns the angle $\theta$ while correctly taking into account the sign of $x$ and $y$?

PS: if you're not familiar with $atan2(y,x)$, this is how it's implemented:
$$
\mathrm{atan2}(y, x) = \left\{ 
\begin{matrix}
 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{if} \,\,[x > 0, y > 0]\\
 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \pi\,\mathrm{if} \,\,[x < 0, y > 0]\\
 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) - \pi\,\mathrm{if} \,\,[x < 0, y < 0]\\
\end{matrix}
\right\}
$$\

Comment: How exactly is the function going to learn about the sign of $x$ and $y$ if you only provide it with their ratio $r$?

Comment: sorry, changed it.

Comment: Now that the function takes two parameters... doesn't $\mathrm{atan2}(x,y)$ just as you described it satisfy your expectations? :-)

Comment: yes on the programming side it's fine, but i need to do some calculus using the rules of my engine, so i need 1 continuous function that can express what's going on at all points of the circle

Comment: What sort of calculus? You might be able to just work with the derivative directly. Also are you just against using a piecewise function?

Comment: Note that $x=0$ and $y=0$ are missing from your set of rules, as is $x>0$, $y<0$. Try as you might, if you coherently paste together as you're trying to do, you can start at  $y=0$, $x>0$ with $\theta=0$ and continue all around in a continuous fashion, and you come back to your starting point with $\theta=2\pi$. No way to prevent that!